# is there a way i can dry this code or use a better approach for this toggle effect

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

i want to make a toggle effect that when you click on an icon it shows some text and the icon toggles away. when you click on the newly displayed text the text toggles away and the icon comes back.

```
`<div class="we-do">
          <img class="icon" src="images/design_icon.png">
          <h5>DESIGN</h5>
          <div class="hide">
           <p class="clickable"> Our design practice offers a full range of services 
            including brand strategy,interaction and
            visual design and user experience testing</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="we-do">
          <img class="icon" src="images/dev_icon.png">
          <h5>DEVELOPMENT</h5>
          <div class="hide">
            <p class="clickable1">All engineers are fluent in the latest enterprise, mobile 
            and web development technologies.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="we-do">
          <img class="icon" src="images/product_icon.png">
          <h5>PRODUCT MANAGEMENT</h5>
          <div class="hide">
            <p class="clickable2">Planning and development is iterative.
             requirements evolve.</p>
          </div>
        </div>enter code here
```

````
  $(".clickable").click(function() {
    $("#hide").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#icon").slideToggle("slow");
  })
  $(".clickable1").click(function() {
    $("#hide1").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#icon1").slideToggle("slow");
  })
  $(".clickable2").click(function() {
   $("#hide2").slideToggle("slow");
   $("#icon2").slideToggle("slow");
  })```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your html has context defined by an outer div of class `we-do`.

```
<div class="we-do">
  <img class="icon" src="images/design_icon.png">
  <h5>DESIGN</h5>
  <div class="hide">
    <p class="clickable">
      Our design practice offers a full range of services 
      including brand strategy,interaction and
      visual design and user experience testing
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Given that, you do not need different classes.  You just need to properly use `contextual lookups`.

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function(e){
  // find the contextual parent to the elements
  var $weDo = $(e.target).closest('.we-do');

  // find the related elements
  var $hide = $weDo.find('.hide');
  var $icon = $weDo.find('.icon');

  // do your work
  $hide.slideToggle("slow");
  $icon.slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: thank you so much, I was thinking of something almost similar.

Comment: The code does not work since clickable is already hidden. i want it such that the icon and heading are visible first then when the icon is clicked on, the description shows and the icon becomes hidden. the opposite should occur when you click on the description.